# Invalid Number Error when Using Non-Numerical Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, Departments and Employees. I want to display the department_id, department_name, and the number of employees in any department that has fewer than 4 employees.

Here's the code that I'm using (I use SQL developer, btw):

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.last_name)
from departments d, employees e
where e.last_name < 4
group by d.department_id, d.department_name;
```

However, I'm getting a invalid number error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `where COUNT(e.last_name) < 4` would make more sense.

Comment: @KenY-N I think you would want to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would make more sense:

```
SELECT d.department_id,
       d.department_name,
       COUNT(*) AS numEmployees
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN employees e
    ON d.department_id = e.department_id
GROUP BY d.department_id,
         d.department_name
HAVING COUNT(*) < 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this code returns an output that displays employee_id, first_name and last_name, email, phone_number, hired_date, job_id, salary, commission_pct, manager_id, and department_id. I only want to display the department_id, department_name, and the number of employees in each of the departments that have fewer than 4 employees.

Comment: @Tim I updated my query to only select the department ID, name, and number of employees per your request.  Great first name, by the way :-)

Comment: Umm, the updated code doesn't work. department_id and department_name are from the departments table, and empcount isn't even one of the columns in employees table (shouldn't we keep it as last_name?). So how do I change that code?

Comment: Hmm, now it says count(*) is an invalid identifier. What is numEmployees, btw? Is that a assigned identifier, because it's not a column in the employees table.

The columns in the Employees table are: employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, hire_date, manager_id, department_id, job_id, salary, and commission_pct.

Comment: Nevermind, it works. It only said invalid identifier because I typed it wrong. Thanks Tim!